# Table design for subtables

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have a table Event which contains ideventtype (references event type), date, idhost,etc.

Now i may have various event type and based on the event type i have fields related to the event type. How do i store these details

Solution 1:-
Save it in the same table as event by adding another column.

Solution 2:-
Create another table, say event_birthday (birthday is the event type) and there i can store the "birthday" related data. However if i have other event types i will have to create many tables, eventually making event type useless.

Any suggestions or other ways to proceed.

[Constraint Added]
Once constraint I have is that the subtable needs to have a foreign key to another table. For example i have a hospital table to be linked to location in the sub table.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a NoSQL database, such as [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/), for this purpose. But if you're stuck with Sql Server, one option would be to save the event details in a generic separate table as xml and use serialization in code to process the values. This way you could still use queries for data filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Two more other ways also possible.

**Solution 3:**

Create another table `EventAddInfo` and that should have 4 columns.

```
EventAddInfoID
EventId
EventSubCol
EventSubValue
```

Here we can store these Extra columns as rows. And `EventId` will be foreign Key from `Event` table.

Example data would be

```
| EventAddInfoID  |EventId   | EventSubCol  | EventSubValue |
|---------------- |----------|--------------|---------------|
| 10              | 4        |  birthdate   |  2002-05-30   |
| 11              | 4        |  birthplace  |  Hospital     |
| 12              | 5        |  Score       |  85           |
| 13              | 5        |  Study       |  Degree       |
```

**Note:** Consider `EventId` 5 related to Study Event

**Solution 4:**

Having one extra column in `Event` Table of type `XML`. 
For example `EventSubInfo`.

In this column we can store xml of our own structure

```
<Cols>
   <birthdate>2002-05-30T09:00:00<birthdate>
   <birthplace>Hospital<birthplace>
</Cols>
```

Comment: Thanks Shakeer, Interesting solution, however if i have the above constraint [recently edited], is there a way that using the 2 solutions you've proposed, the constraint can be resolved.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting added constraint. Do you want to add Foreign Key in hospital table? If so you can add directly `EventAddInfoID` as foreign key in `Hospital` table @user2327579

Comment: If my understanding is wrong, can you explain me with example in the question? @user2327579

Comment: Ok so taking yout example, say i have a table "Study" which stores a list of possible values("Degree","Master",etc) that needs to be referenced to the "EventSubCol". It will not be possible to do that as there may be another table to be referenced.